# Knitr - non-english letters

Tags: r, encoding, knitr

I'm trying to create a simply pdf document using knitr package in R but I'm stuck with non-english (polish) letter. The code looks as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\large
\textbf{ąćółńóśźż}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

My session info:

```
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows XP (build 2600) Service Pack 3

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Polish_Poland.1250  LC_CTYPE=Polish_Poland.1250    LC_MONETARY=Polish_Poland.1250 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Polish_Poland.1250    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] cairoDevice_2.22 RGtk2_2.20.31    knitr_1.10.5     plyr_1.8.3       beepr_1.2        scales_0.2.5     ggplot2_1.0.1    quantmod_0.4-5  
 [9] TTR_0.23-0       xts_0.9-7        zoo_1.7-12       RODBC_1.3-12    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] audio_0.1-5      colorspace_1.2-6 digest_0.6.8     evaluate_0.7     formatR_1.2      grid_3.1.3       gtable_0.1.2     lattice_0.20-33 
 [9] magrittr_1.5     MASS_7.3-43      munsell_0.4.2    proto_0.3-10     Rcpp_0.12.0      reshape2_1.4.1   stringi_0.5-5    stringr_1.0.0   
[17] tools_3.1.3
```

I read similar topics and tried to change encoding but it doesn't work. 
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is encoding related. Technically this problem has two faces: input encoding and output encoding.
When you use `LaTeX` (like this case) you have to specify where to find the right symbols (with the keyboard) and after that system must know where (inside the system) to find the symbols you have typed. Imagine it like a sort of drawer with millions of things, you have just to tell your system the coordinates of the proper symbol you want.

Add this to your preamble (say, the part before `\begin{document}`). The final code will be. Please note that the order of the `usepackage`s sometimes does no matter other times it does. This time it does matter!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\large
\textbf{ąćółńóśźż}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```